# Carry / use value from previous group

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

data:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5), 
               ax = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
                      "d", "d", "e"), time = c(1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 9, 10, 
                                               11, 12)), .Names = c("id", "ax", "time"), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                   "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

looks like:

```
    id ax time
 1:  1  a    1
 2:  1  a    3
 3:  2  b    0
 4:  2  b    2
 5:  2  b    4
 6:  2  b    5
 7:  2  b    6
 8:  2  b    8
 9:  3  c    7
10:  3  c    9
11:  4  d   10
12:  4  d   11
13:  5  e   12
```

I want to have the `max` of the previous group next to the actual group:

desired output:

```
    id ax time newCol
 1:  1  a    1     NA
 2:  1  a    3     NA
 3:  2  b    0      3
 4:  2  b    2      3
 5:  2  b    4      3
 6:  2  b    5      3
 7:  2  b    6      3
 8:  2  b    8      3
 9:  3  c    7      8
10:  3  c    9      8
11:  4  d   10      9
12:  4  d   11      9
13:  5  e   12     11
```

Is it also possible to have the value of the "previous-previous" grp?

Interessted in `baseR`, `data.table` and `tidyverse` solutions

#### note:

Can be grouped by EITHER `id` or `ax`. The example is a little redundant here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `data.table` solution:

```
dtt.max <- dtt[, .(max = max(time)), by = ax]
dtt.max[, max.prev := shift(max)]

dtt[dtt.max, newCol := i.max.prev, on = 'ax']
# > dtt
#     id ax time newCol
#  1:  1  a    1     NA
#  2:  1  a    3     NA
#  3:  2  b    0      3
#  4:  2  b    2      3
#  5:  2  b    4      3
#  6:  2  b    5      3
#  7:  2  b    6      3
#  8:  2  b    8      3
#  9:  3  c    7      8
# 10:  3  c    9      8
# 11:  4  d   10      9
# 12:  4  d   11      9
# 13:  5  e   12     11
```

Answer (score 3):

`data.table` solution using `id + 1`

```
library(data.table)
merge(d, setDT(d)[, max(time), id + 1], all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: have thought of something similar then shift/roll the id variable.

Comment: @AndreElrico If `id` is numeric then simply adding integer is a straightforward solution.

Comment: sure in that case. But could of course be possible that an id is missing etc... anyways good stuff!!!

Comment: somehow i get the following error: `Error in gmax(time) : grpn [13] != length(x) [11] in gmax`

Comment: @AndreElrico I'm using `data.table 1.10.4.3`

Comment: To add it by reference instead of making a new table: `DT[DT[, max(time), by=id+1], on=.(id), v := i.V1]` or `DT[DT[, max(time), by=id][, id := shift(id, type="lead")], on=.(id), v := i.V1]`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `dplyr` approach. The key here is to group and ungroup when necessary:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ax) %>% 
  mutate(new = time[n()]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(new = lag(new)) %>%
  group_by(ax) %>%
  mutate(new = new[1])

# A tibble: 13 x 4
# Groups:   ax [5]
      id ax     time   new
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1    1. a        1.   NA 
 2    1. a        3.   NA 
 3    2. b        0.    3.
 4    2. b        2.    3.
 5    2. b        4.    3.
 6    2. b        5.    3.
 7    2. b        6.    3.
 8    2. b        8.    3.
 9    3. c        7.    8.
10    3. c        9.    8.
11    4. d       10.    9.
12    4. d       11.    9.
13    5. e       12.   11.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `id` is the same as `group`:

```
dfr <- dfr %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(groupmax = max(time))
dfr$old_group_max <- dfr$groupmax[match(dfr$id - 1, dfr$id)]
```

The antepenultimate group is left as an exercise :-)

Answer (score 1):

**1)** This uses no packages. It computes the maximum for each group giving `Ag` and and then lags it giving `LagMax`.  Finally it left joins using `merge` that back into the original data frame `DF`:

```
Ag <- aggregate(time ~ id, DF, max)
LagMax <- transform(Ag, lagmax = c(NA, head(time, -1)), time = NULL)
merge(DF, LagMax, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
   id ax time lagmax
1   1  a    1     NA
2   1  a    3     NA
3   2  b    0      3
4   2  b    2      3
5   2  b    4      3
6   2  b    5      3
7   2  b    6      3
8   2  b    8      3
9   3  c    7      8
10  3  c    9      8
11  4  d   10      9
12  4  d   11      9
13  5  e   12     11
```

**2)** This sorts time within id so that we know that the maximum is the last value in each id group.

```
o <- order(factor(DF$id, levels = unique(DF$id)), DF$time)
Time <- DF$time[o]
lagmax <- function(r) if (r[1] == 1) NA else Time[r[1] - 1]
transform(DF, lagmax = ave(seq_along(id), id, FUN = lagmax))
```

In the question the `time` values are already sorted within `id` and if that is known to be the case the above could be shortened to:

```
lagmax <- function(r) if (r[1] == 1) NA else DF$time[r[1] - 1]
transform(DF, lagmax = ave(seq_along(id), id, FUN = lagmax))
```

**3)** This one-liner is a data.table translation of (2):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- copy(DF) # don't overwrite DF

setDT(DT)[, g:=rleid(id)][, lagmax := DT$time[.I[1]-1], keyby = c("g", "id")]
```

In the sample data in the question `time` is sorted within `id` and if that were known to be the case we could use the following shorter code in place of the last line above

```
setDT(DT)[, lagmax := DT$time[.I[1]-1], by = id]
```